# ISOLATION LEVEL in DB2

Tags: db2, isolation

Questions:

1. Does their is an ISOLATION level in DB2 at database level ?
2. What is the default ISOLATION LEVEL in DB2 at database level Database ?
3. How can we change the ISOLATION LEVEL in DB2 at database level ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a reliable way to guarantee the isolation level when an application connects to the database; the client application should set the desired isolation level.
As an example when I first connect toa DB2 database on Linux or AIX the isolation is NULL.

`db2 -x "values(current isolation)"`